# psql version incorrectly showing 15 instead of 14

Tags: server, postgresql

psql version shows 15 but we have the version 14 cluster online, while 12 and 15 are down.

```
12  main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
14  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
15  main    5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log
```

when I execute `readlink /usr/bin/psql` I see

```
../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

/usr/bin/psql should be pointing to version 14

Any help on what could be going wrong would be great?

Comment: thanks for your response, i am not sure how to do that, can you please provide me some example commands or point me to documentation where i can check this?

Comment: Oops, the wrapper was perl, not bash.  try something like perl -d:Trace /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper